# jQuery: Update CSS content property

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to dynamically set the *content* property of a CSS Style using jQuery. In the following Fiddle, I'd like the output to read "100% Completed" after the script executes.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dwueyL1/2/)

I've tried just about every combination of CSS Selectors I could think of, and have failed miserably.

HTML

```
<div data-chart="1">
  <div class="chart"><span> Completed</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
[data-chart="1"] .chart:before {
  content: "50%";
}
```

JS

```
// This obviously doesn't work
$('[data-chart="1"] .donut-chart:before').css('content', '100%');
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Relevant: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)  *css :after and :before rules aren't part of the DOM, and therefore can't be selected using DOM methods*

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think of that (pseudo-elements not part of the DOM). Makes perfect sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in some answers on the relevant post linked in the comments, you could use the `attr()` function in CSS:

```
[data-chart="1"] .chart:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}
```

And change the content like:

```
$('[data-chart=1] .chart').attr('data-before', '100%');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5jrL8g19/